# JavaScript Regexp: successive matches

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I'm writing a lexical scanner in JavaScript. There're an `inputStr` and a list of regexps `[ regexp1, regexp2, ... ]`, I need to match the `inputStr` with the list of regexps successively. Suppose `regexps[i]` matches the first 5 characters of the `inputStr`, I'll continue to do the matching from the 6-th character.

I checked the JavaScript RegExp API, I didn't see any way to control matching a string from a specified index. The `lastIndex` property of RegExp object doesn't work in this case, because if the character at `lastIndex` is not matched, it will try to match from the next character, but I want it stopps immediately.

Comment: You can replace the matched area with empty string and repeat the matches. I think that an OR between regexps with global flag enabled may work too.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're right, there isn't anything built-in that will help you do that.

Three options:

1. The obvious thing: Use a `^` in the regular expressions (so they only match at the beginning of the input) and remove the previously-matched characters (e.g., those first five in your example) from the string before continuing.
2. Create new regexes with dynamically-generated prefixes like `^.{5}` (e.g., to skip the first five characters), but I would *assume* (which is dangerous) that that would be more expensive than slicing up the string. You could, of course, create the regexes on demand but keep and reuse them; that has memory implications of course.
3. Go ahead and use `lastIndex` but disregard the match unless it's at the index you want it to be at. This is wasteful (the regex engine works to find a match that you may well disregard) and I don't like it, but I figured might as well list it.

I'd probably start with option 1 (the simple option) and only consider alternatives if I were fairly sure it was creating a performance or memory churn issue. But JavaScript engines create and clean up a *lot* of temporary strings, I'd assume V8 was pretty good at managing them.